# jstack command not found on centos

Tags: linux, java, centos, jdk

I installed JDK by downloading the RPM from oracle and installed it using yum. But the jstack command is not recognized. I'm using CentOS 6.3 How can I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably just not in your $PATH for some reason. Try searching for the command:

```
sudo updatedb
locate jstack
```